# Host.CreateDefaultBuilder vs Host.CreateApplicationBuilder in .NET Platform Extension 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-7.0

We generally Create Host using the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()`
Method.
The `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` returns an `IHostBuilder`.
The `IHostBuilder` has some extension methods by which we can configure the builder. After configuring the `IHostBuilder` We build the `IHost` by `IHostBuilder.Build()`.

But on .NET Platform Extension 7, a new method is introduced `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()`.
It gives us an `HostApplicationBuilder` instance.
It doesn't have extension methods like `IHostBuilder` to configure, but it has some properties such as Configuration, Environment, Logging, Services, etc.
And using `HostApplicationBuilder.Build()` we can eventually Build the `IHost`.

My question is when and why we should build Host using the `HostApplicationBuilder` instead of `IHostBuilder`?
And how to configure srvices, configurations, etc on `HostApplicationBuilder`, do we need to directly use its properties(Configuration, Environment, Logging, Services, etc)?

I tried searching on google but got no answer.

Comment: There's a bit of documentation about this "improvement" here...
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61634

Answer (score 36):

It is documented a bit [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/81090) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61634).

> The general idea was to move away from calbacks and move to linear code for configuring everything

Code samples from the link...

**Web**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.Logging.AddConsole();

builder.Services.AddOptions<MyOptions>().BindConfiguration("MyConfig");

builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World");

app.Run();
```

**Non-Web**

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

builder.Logging.AddConsole();

builder.Services.AddOptions<MyOptions>().BindConfiguration("MyConfig");

builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>();

var host = builder.Build();

host.Run();
```

**Update 2023-11-23**

In summary, the old Host.CreateDefaultBuilder method is being phased out and the new methods adopt an approach of "move away from calbacks and move to linear code".

This means the properties on HostApplicationBuilder should be used, but third party libraries will need to update so their extensions methods cater for it. For example Serilog had a [discussion](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1855) on this.

Example code using Host.CreateApplicationBuilder:

```
var applicationBuilder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

applicationBuilder.Logging.AddConsole();

applicationBuilder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

applicationBuilder.Environment.ApplicationName = "My Application";

applicationBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
```

Comment: I don't understand the answer. The question is about Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() and Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(), but the answer is about WebApplication.CreateBuilder() and Host.CreateApplicationBuilder().
Can anyone answer the actual question? : D

Comment: Like the quote mentions they have changed it and you now use properties instead of callbacks.

Comment: @EmilijaVilijaTrečiokaitė I think what he's attempting to say is that the (newer) `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()` is similar in design to `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()`, unlike the (older) `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` approach, which was quite different, thereby making setup of both web and non-web applications more similar.

Comment: Using HostApplicationBuilder how do you configure host specific things?  Is there any way to access the IHostBuilder, similar to the WebApplicationBuilder?

Comment: I think it's misleading to use `applicationBuilder.Logging.AddConsole();` or `applicationBuilder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");` within these examples. 
They are already done by default by both `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();` and `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()` and thus simply redundants.