# Serilog into .NET 8 Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, .net-8.0, worker-service

In .net 7 we had `IHostBuilder` and the following code was working using nuget package `Serilog.AspNetCore`

```
.UseSerilog((context, config) => config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration))
```

In .net 8 we have `HostApplicationBuilder`. how would we use Serilog with auto generated template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Host.CreateDefaultBuilder vs Host.CreateApplicationBuilder in .NET Platform Extension 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229793/host-createdefaultbuilder-vs-host-createapplicationbuilder-in-net-platform-exte)

Comment: You use .Services.UseSerilog() to set up Serilog with HostApplicationBuilder.

Comment: Thanks @silkfire for the comment, I'm using this code Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSerilog(....). it is extension method for IHostBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `HostApplicationBuilder.Services` object. Here is a code snippet to show you how to use SeriLog with .NET 8 worker service.

```
    using Serilog;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddSerilog(lc => lc
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(Path.Join(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "myApp.log")));


            builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            var host = builder.Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was also searching for this information. Found something in [this page](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/issues/76) which helped me to find exactly what I was looking for, to use the config file:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSerilog(config => { config.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration); });
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```