# Serilog .NET 8 Windows Service (worker) using BackgroundService Logs not found

Tags: .net-core, serilog, .net-8.0

My goal is to use Serilog for file logging in a Windows service using the .NET 8 Worker template.

I can see console logs. I just couldn't find the log file.

**Note: See updates at the end**

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
using GettingStartedSvc;
using Serilog;

var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

// The initial bootstrap logger is able to log errors during start-up.
// It's fully replaced by the logger configured in `UseSerilog()`.
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information("Starting up...");

try
{
    builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
    // configures the app to work as a Windows Service.
    builder.Services.AddWindowsService(ops =>
    {
        ops.ServiceName = "DotNet Joke Service";
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<JokeService>();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();

    var host = builder.Build();
    host.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occured during bootstrapping");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

`JokeService.cs`

```
namespace GettingStartedSvc;

public sealed class JokeService
{
    public string GetJoke()
    {
        Joke joke = _jokes.ElementAt(Random.Shared.Next(_jokes.Count));
        return $"{joke.Setup}{Environment.NewLine}{joke.Punchline}";
    }

    private readonly HashSet<Joke> _jokes = new()
    {
        new Joke("What's the best thing about a Boolean?", "Even if you're wrong, you're only off by a bit."),
        new Joke("What's the object-oriented way to become wealthy?", "Inheritance"),
        new Joke("Why did the programmer quit their job?", "Because they didn't get arrays.")
    };

}

readonly record struct Joke(string Setup, string Punchline);
```

`WindowsBackgroundService.cs`

```
namespace GettingStartedSvc;

public sealed class WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly JokeService _jokeService;

    public WindowsBackgroundService(
        ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> logger,
        JokeService jokeService
    )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _jokeService = jokeService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                string joke = _jokeService.GetJoke();
                _logger.LogWarning("{Joke}", joke);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException opCanceledEx)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var joke = _jokeService.GetJoke();
            _logger.LogWarning("{Joke}", joke);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update - #1 : 01/24 - Does Not Work**

I wonder why this does not work
I call `AddSerilog` on the `Services` instead of `Logging`

`Program.cs`

```
try
{
    // builder.Logging.AddSerilog();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom
        .Configuration(builder.Configuration) //read config from appsettings
        .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger);

    // configures the app to work as a Windows Service.
    builder.Services.AddWindowsService(ops =>
    {
        ops.ServiceName = "DotNet Joke Service";
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<JokeService>();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();

    var host = builder.Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

**Update - #2 : 01/24 - Works**

Slight modifications to the `program.cs` class and not picking configuration from `appsettings.json` and instead configure via code seem to be creating the log file.

However, I still am interested to know why the configuration provided in this post under the `appsettings.json` section does not create a log file???

I suspect something goes wrong with respect to the path of the log file. But I don't know what exactly is that!

`Program.cs`

```
try
{
    // builder.Logging.AddSerilog();

    // var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom
    //     .Configuration(builder.Configuration) //read config from appsettings
    //     .CreateLogger();
    // builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger);

    builder.Services.AddSerilog(
    lc =>
        lc.MinimumLevel
            .Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(Path.Join(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "myApp.log"))
    );

    // configures the app to work as a Windows Service.
    builder.Services.AddWindowsService(ops =>
    {
        ops.ServiceName = "DotNet Joke Service";
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<JokeService>();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();

    var host = builder.Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user running your service has enough filesystem access to write to the app's folder? You could also enable [Serilog's selflog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) to see if there are any errors there

Comment: alternately tools such as sysinternals filemon and/or other such tools can tell you where things are writingt/rying to write but failing at a lower level too

Comment: It's likely that an [unexpected current directory](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/10/managed-windows-services-basics.html) is throwing you off (as explained on my blog). A common workaround is to set the current directory to your exe's directory on startup.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this package `Serilog.AspNetCore` and use "Services.Addxxx" instead of "logging.Addxxx"

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)   //read config from appsettings
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: I believe the AspNetCore package is to work with AspNet web apps. I am not sure if this can be used in a windows service. however, modifications to the program.cs class as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77743177 seems working

Comment: @blogs4t I also tested in a worker service template. From my test, your appsettings is all good.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (.NET 8 Console app):

```
builder.Services.AddSerilog(lc => lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));
```

The log file ends up in the current directory (in my case it's the location where the executable is, `bin\Debug\net8.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what work for me using .NET 8...

Add the following NuGet Packages:

- Serilog Version 3.1.1
- Serilog.Extensions.Hosting Version 8.0.0
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration Version 8.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Console Version 5.0.1
- Serilog.Sinks.File Version 5.0.0

Here's my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithThreadId"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\temp\\logs\\App.logs",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInternval": "Day",
          "shared": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The Program.cs file

```
using Serilog;

var builder = Host
    .CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

// The initial bootstrap logger is able to log errors during start-up.
// It's fully replaced by the logger configured in `UseSerilog()`.
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateBootstrapLogger();

try
{
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)   //read config from appsettings
        .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger);

    // configures the app to work as a Windows Service.
    builder
        .Services
        .AddWindowsService(options =>
        {
            options.ServiceName = "Glenwood.Orchestra";
        })
        .AddHostedService<Worker>();

    IHost host = builder.Build();
    host.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occured during bootstrapping");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Last but not least, the Work.cs file

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            _logger.LogError(oce.Message, oce);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```