# Is UseConsoleLifetime included by default in .NET Generic Host (Host.CreateDefaultBuilder)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

I initially configured my Console application using .NET generic host as follows:

```cs
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddLogging();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
    {
        configLogging.AddConsole();
    })
    .UseConsoleLifetime()
    .Build();

await builder.RunAsync();
```

Then I realized I also needed `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, which led me to the decision to use `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`, as it includes the default logging, appsettings, and some other defaults:

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
    })
    .UseConsoleLifetime() // Is this line necessary?
    .Build();
```

Now I wonder if UseConsoleLifetime is actually included in the default builder. I wasn't able to find it by decompiling several source code files, but just to be sure, I decided to ask this question.

Here is the Microsoft docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=hostbuilder
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder#host-shutdown

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229793/host-createdefaultbuilder-vs-host-createapplicationbuilder-in-net-platform-exte is also useful as they've introduced `CreateApplicationBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. The only thing [`UseConsoleLifetime`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs,345) actually does is that it registers `ConsoleLifetime` as `IHostLifetime`. And `ConsoleLifetime` is the default one. From the [generic hosting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder#ihostlifetime):

> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ConsoleLifetime` is the default `IHostLifetime` implementation.

And it is easy to check it out:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
var build = builder.Build();
Console.WriteLine(build.Services.GetService<IHostLifetime>() is ConsoleLifetime); // prints "True"
```

If you wonder where the lifetime is set by default - see the [`AddLifetime`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostBuilder.netcoreapp.cs,3c464e7ce4dc99fe) call in the [`HostBuilder.PopulateServiceCollection`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostBuilder.cs,313) which is called both by `HostBuilder` itself (i.e. `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`) and [`HostApplicationBuilder`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostApplicationBuilder.cs,176) (i.e. `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()`).

Also consider using `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()` since it seems more in line with current approach to setting up the application.

Comment: Thank you very much, and thanks for telling me how to check it! :) I realized `CreateApplicationBuilder` includes it by putting a breakpoint at https://i.imgur.com/unr485B.png

Comment: @nop was glad to help! Also added some sources responsible for setting the default lifetime.